# PCA projection on data

Tags: r, pca, eigenvector

I have to do a principal components analysis on a data set. I have done that using the
princomp()
function. I am then asked to visualize the data by a scatter plot, where I project the data on the first two principal components.

The returned object form the princomp() function has has a class 'loadings' with the eigenvectors.

How do I substract the two first principals components and project them on my data in a scatter plot?

Edit:
I used biplot(princom(df)) as suggested:

```
pdf('scatterplot.pdf')

biplot(princomp(keytrain, choices = 1:2), xlab = '1. component', ylab = '2. component')
title('Scatterplot of the first two components projected on the data')

dev.off()
```

Where keytrain is my data frame.
I was given this plot:

[image: Scatter plot]

Does that look reasonable?

Comment: take a look at `?biplot`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me interpret the scatter plot? I have what looks like all 21 vectors (my dataframe has 21 variables) - I am however only asked to project the first 2 components. I will update my question with a picture of the scatterplot.

Comment: RStudent: Are the information I have provided in my edit sufficient?

Comment: Actually, you already have presented the data according to first two principal components in the plot you provide (look at the axes)

Comment: Yes I realized that, but I have trouble to  interpret the scatter plot. Should I just understand it as the 21-dimensional data is now represented in a 2-dimensional space? (the two first principal components cover >50% of the variance). I have 640 observations, so I interpret the numbers (points) to represent each observation in the 2-dimensional space.

Comment: Yes. And in this case a rotation would make sense, so that V8 largely corresponds to 2. pc and the other variables correspond to 1. pc.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I am pretty new to machine learning and really want to understand what I am doing.

Comment: This method was invented more than a 100 years ago by statisticians and is now being "reinvented" as a ML technique. :rolleyes: :)

Answer (score 0):

The `princomp` object produces a list of elements (S3 object). You can inspect its structure via `str`.

```
(pc.cr <- princomp(USArrests))

> str(pc.cr)
List of 7
 $ sdev    : Named num [1:4] 82.89 14.07 6.42 2.46
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4"
 $ loadings: loadings [1:4, 1:4] -0.0417 -0.9952 -0.0463 -0.0752 0.0448 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4"
 $ center  : Named num [1:4] 7.79 170.76 65.54 21.23
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
 $ scale   : Named num [1:4] 1 1 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
 $ n.obs   : int 50
 $ scores  : num [1:50, 1:4] -64.8 -92.8 -124.1 -18.3 -107.4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "Alabama" "Alaska" "Arizona" "Arkansas" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4"
 $ call    : language princomp(x = USArrests)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "princomp"
```

Scores are accessible through `pc.cr$scores`.

Comment: If I am to project the on the first two principal components, should I not use the loadings instead of the scores?